# Clockpicker not displaying clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, clockpicker

I have a problem using a clockpicker (http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/).

It behaves like a textbox, and it does not show the clock. I do not know what the problem could be, since I included the necessary scripts and stylesheets in the `<head>` of the html:

```
<link href="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
```

I also downladed the assets, placed them in the project, and imported them like this:

```
<script th:src="@{/assets/js/plugins/clockpicker/clockpicker.js}" src="js/plugins/clockpicker/clockpicker.js"></script>
```

This is the html code that displays the textbox and the little clock icon:

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker" style="width: 50%; float: left;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

AND the jquery activation:

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
```

I have absolutely no idea what needs to be done, so any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/q1skrndg/

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: @artgb I'm sorry if it is not what you expect, I never used it before: https://jsfiddle.net/q1skrndg/

Comment: There is powerful clockpicker example here http://jsfiddle.net/weareoutman/YkvK9/

Comment: Also your fiddle is working https://jsfiddle.net/q1skrndg/2/, link was changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it, the problem was I was adding the clockpicker as a jquery object, and the activation `$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();` was made before the element was drown in the page, so it was nothing to activate. I think I still have to work a lot with jquery to fully understand it. Thank you all anyway :D

Answer (score 3):

Its working fine i think you missed adding `Jquery` in header

```js
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group clockpicker" style="width: 50%; float: left;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
</div>
<script>
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
</script>
```

Comment: I did miss to add it, but it was not the main problem, I will extend in an answer.

Comment: `JQuery` is required for every 3rd party jquery plugins

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 4 2020: clock icon not showing, but clock itself does**

If you are using Bootstrap 4, the clock icon may not be showing for another reason, namely changes in Bootstrap classes.

The **Bootstrap class `<span class="input-group-addon">`**, as found on [the ClockPicker docs](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/), **is no longer used in Bootstrap 4.**

You now need to use the **Bootstrap class `<span class="input-group-append">`** or **`<span class="input-group-prepend">`** as you can find here [as you can find here](http:///https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/), and the interior `span` needs the class **`<span class="input-group-text">`.**

So you need to substitute:

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

with something like:

```
<div className="input-group clockpicker">
  <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue="" placeholder="Now"></input>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ClockPicker is no longer being maintained by [weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) but is now maintained by [djibe](https://github.com/djibe) [here](https://github.com/djibe/clockpicker/tree/gh-pages/dist).** You can see a working example from djibe on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/9wj67d5u/).

His newer version has some styling changes and updates that are well worth integrating.